# How to uninstall Hotspot Shield's VPN adapter driver?

Tags: drivers, uninstall, hotspot, hotspot-shield, revo-uninstaller

After installing Hotspot with Revo Uninstaller then uninstalling it completely from my system, I'm still left with Hotspot's VPN adapter driver.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/G6NYV.png]

This bothers me a great deal. Unfortunately I did not make a system backup prior to installing Hotspot. Uninstalling it from hardware devices does nothing.

Searching for * hss*.* which is associated with said driver, gives me this result:

[image]

How can I uninstall this driver?

Answer (score -1):

Boot Windows in safe mode and perform the uninstall.  It will ask you if you want to remove drivers.  Choose yes.